# OneSignal - Sending silent notifications that only increment badge (app in background)

Tags: ionic-framework, onesignal

My app (iOS) is in background and I want to send a push notification that won't display anything (silent) and that will only increment badge count on the app's icon.

I am still not clear on how to manage that.

Is it a parameter in the message body or in my handler code?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever manage to accomplish this?

Comment: Unfortunately no...

Answer (score 0):

Try to send a push notification with `content-available=1`

> 1. Turn on the content-available (iOS) or silent-notification (Android)
>      fields. This will cause your application to be automatically woken
>      up in the background whenever a notification is received (even if
>      it's not clicked). Your custom code must be write with native code,
>      Java on Android and Swift or Objective-C on iOS. See Apple's
>      content-available for iOS and our Android Background Data guides for
>      details on receiving and processing the event.
> 2. In your app, we
>      provide an API that you can use to run custom code when the above
>      occurs. Your custom code can then save a copy of the notification
>      content on the device in order to be displayed in an activity feed
>      when the app is next launched. Or it could save a copy of it on your
>      servers.

https://documentation.onesignal.com/v3.0/reference